# How can I make a "mobile" boundary in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, boundary

I've been working on an Undertale fangame and I'm facing a problem. In the fight box, the Player's soul (aka character) can pass the Edge Collider and go through the edge. I was thinking about using a Boundary instead, but I want to make the fight box move during the attacks, so I need to move the boundaries with the box. How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with an edge collider.
It's important that you use the EdgeCollider**2D**, because it is a 2D game. Does your player have some sort of Collider**2d** as well and is the "Is Trigger" option set to false on both colliders?
If you then want to move the EdgeCollider2D, you can just move the GameObject.

Comment: The problem is that the player collides with the EdgeCollider2D, but even so, he can exit the box after a while moving against it

Comment: Do you directly change the transform.position? You should rather move the player with the Rigidbody2D with rb.MovePosition() or changing the rb.velocity. Then it should work better.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was reading the documentation and was wondering if that was what I needed